# problem while sorting a linked list (pseudocode)?

Tags: sorting, linked-list, pseudocode

I was trying to figure out a way to sort a linked list in ascending or descending order, but because a linked list is accessed only sequentially, I don't know how to do it, let me explain it better,
this is a code sketch of navigating a linked list in C (for the sake of this question, it's not important what list implementation do you use, it's only about the algorithm design of this specific problem):

```
Item* tmp = i; // i is a list, and tmp is a pointer to the list, 
while(!listisempty(tmp)) {
// do something
tmp = tmp->next; 
}
```

this is a possible way to navigate the linked list, I can only access the current element and the next element, i can't access directly the last element to sort the list efficiently,

```
Item* tmp = i; // i is a list, and tmp is a pointer to the list, 
    while(!listisempty(tmp)) {
    if (current > next) {
    swap(current, next);
}
    tmp = tmp->next; 
    }
```

but this idea is not efficient, because i have to navigate the linked list multiple times in order to sort the list.

is there a way of starting with an arbitrary element in the list in order to sort it?

[I can try the gnome sort (i.e stupid sort), but it's not efficient and therefore i've ignored it (plus, the list can be long and it may require a lot of steps)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that a linked list can only be traversed sequentially.

However, there are sorting algorithms that don't need much else. A classic candidate for linked lists is merge sort. You can take the top-down approach or the bottom-up approach. A key concept is that you split the list into smaller lists, until your list has only one element, and can be considered sorted. True, to split a list in the middle, you'll have to traverse the list, but that should not be considered an issue.

Then you only need a function that can merge two sorted linked lists, mutating the `next` property of the least node to the next least node, ...etc, so forming one merged, sorted list.

If you keep doing that, you'll end up with a sorted linked list.

This process has a time complexity of O(log), which is what can be expected of an efficient sorting algorithm.

Alternatively, you can also look into ideas of quick sort: creating partitions would translate to creating separated lists, where you append elements to the correct partition-list depending on how they compare with a pivot.